# Python Tkinter Animation

Tags: python, animation, python-2.7, tkinter

Why is the animation not working? The shape doesn't move when I run the program.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time



class alien(object):
     def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=400, height = 400)
        self.canvas.pack()
        alien1 = self.canvas.create_oval(20, 260, 120, 360, outline='white',         fill='blue')
        alien2 = self.canvas.create_oval(2, 2, 40, 40, outline='white', fill='red')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

     def animation(self):
        track = 0
        while True:
        x = 5
        y = 0
        if track == 0:
           for i in range(0,51):
                self.time.sleep(0.025)
                self.canvas.move(alien1, x, y)
                self.canvas.move(alien2, x, y)
                self.canvas.update()
           track = 1
           print "check"

        else:
           for i in range(0,51):
                self.time.sleep(0.025)
                self.canvas.move(alien1, -x, y)
                self.canvas.move(alien2, -x, y)
                self.canvas.update()
           track = 0
        print track

alien()
```

Comment: was trying to get the oval to move from left to right on the x-xis

Comment: is there something that i need to import ? because i looked up forum online and it make sense to only import Tkinter and timer, not sure what i am missing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never called the `animation` method. There were a couple of other naming issues.

```
# Assuming Python 2.x
# For Python 3.x support change print -> print(..) and Tkinter to tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import time

class alien(object):
     def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=400, height = 400)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.alien1 = self.canvas.create_oval(20, 260, 120, 360, outline='white',         fill='blue')
        self.alien2 = self.canvas.create_oval(2, 2, 40, 40, outline='white', fill='red')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.root.after(0, self.animation)
        self.root.mainloop()

     def animation(self):
        track = 0
        while True:
            x = 5
            y = 0
            if track == 0:
               for i in range(0,51):
                    time.sleep(0.025)
                    self.canvas.move(self.alien1, x, y)
                    self.canvas.move(self.alien2, x, y)
                    self.canvas.update()
               track = 1
               print "check"

            else:
               for i in range(0,51):
                    time.sleep(0.025)
                    self.canvas.move(self.alien1, -x, y)
                    self.canvas.move(self.alien2, -x, y)
                    self.canvas.update()
               track = 0
            print track

alien()
```

Comment: wow i wouldn't of caught those mistake, can u give tips on how to become i good programmer? any website or book that may help me improve on this hobby because i Find it very interesting.... and thank you very much sir!!!

Comment: Practice as much as possible and pay attention to small details. In this case, all the naming issues were identified by reading the error messages when the program was run.

Comment: Putting sleeps in the code is a bad idea. Even though they are short, every time you sleep the entire GUI will be unresponsive.

Answer (score 22):

Your `animation` method has a `while True` loop in it which never breaks. This is a no-no in a GUI program, because by never returning, it prevents the GUI's event-loop from processing events. So, for example, if you had a Menu, then the user would not be able to select any menu item. The GUI would appear frozen, except for whatever actions you implement in the `animation` method.

Here is a slight modification of @Tim's code which fixes this problem by removing the `while` loop and simply moving the aliens one step before returning. `self.master.after` is called at the end of the `animation` method to have the event loop call animation again after a short pause.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class Alien(object):
    def __init__(self, canvas, *args, **kwargs):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(*args, **kwargs)
        self.vx = 5
        self.vy = 0

    def move(self):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvas.bbox(self.id)
        if x2 > 400:
            self.vx = -5
        if x1 < 0:
            self.vx = 5
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.vx, self.vy)

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.aliens = [
            Alien(self.canvas, 20, 260, 120, 360,
                  outline='white', fill='blue'),
            Alien(self.canvas, 2, 2, 40, 40, outline='white', fill='red'),
        ]
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.master.after(0, self.animation)

    def animation(self):
        for alien in self.aliens:
            alien.move()
        self.master.after(12, self.animation)

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: o ic, but what is the difference between from Tkinter import *
and import Tkinter as tk??

Comment: `from Tkinter import *` imports the `Tkinter` module and adds all the (public) globals from the `Tkinter` module into the current module's namespace. `import Tkinter as tk` imports the `Tkinter` module and adds the module object itself -- referenced by `tk` -- to the current module's namespace. I never use `from modulename import *` because it makes it harder to trace where variables come from. See [this FAQ](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module) for advice on "best practices" for using import in a module.

Comment: @unutbu Nice, if we want to use a more complex gui with animations, we put the animation in the "animation" method and then, the gui itself, with something like event management should be in or called by the _____init_____ function, after the self.master.after. I'm right ? or it should be before ?

Comment: @Yann: I would build the GUI as normal (and which is usually done in `App.__init__`) and at the end of `App.__init_`, call `self.master.after(0, self.animation)`. Think of it this way: you get all the widgets in place, and then add an action (the calling of `self.animation`) to the event loop.

Comment: @unutbu ok ty ! I'm on it. Feel the power of python :3

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way of doing it using a loop:

```
from tkinter import * # version 3.x

tk = Tk()

frame = Frame(tk)
canvas = Canvas(frame) # use canvas

frame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

ball = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 30, 30, tags = 'ball') # create object to animate

def animation(x_move, y_move):
    canvas.move(ball, x_move, y_move) # movement
    canvas.update()
    canvas.after(20) # milliseconds in wait time, this is 50 fps

    tk.after_idle(animation, x_move, y_move) # loop variables and animation, these are updatable variables

animation(2, 2) # run animation
```

An updatable variable is a variable that stays the same when updated and can be updated again.

Comment: I got a lot smoother program by removing `canvas.update()` and `canvas.after_idle(...)` and instead using `canvas.after(20, animation, x_move, y_move)`. Also add a `tk.mainloop()` after the last line.

Comment: i am informed but i am now using advanced Opengl with shaders and 3d lighting in c++ and thanks for the input! Opengl is better than tkinter though...